# How to find a specific component with LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

I'm having trouble every time I need to find a component with LTspice. Normally I manage to find what I need. but not for the current component.

I need a 2N2222 transistor. I've tried to enter words in the component search toolbar for transistor, but nothing. I tried to enter the code, nothing.

I wonder what the best way is when you know the component you need to search, because every time I need a new one, it ends up being a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For standard components like transistors, diodes, inductors and capacitors the selectable components are not inside the component placement tool, but in a separate dialog.

So you select your standard component (npn transistor in this case) and place it on your schematic.

After that "rightclick" it. A window opens with general information about the part. It also contains a button labelled "Pick new transistor". Click that button and you end up with this:

[image: selecting a different transistor in LTSpice]

You can sort by part number or other parameters.

One thing to note though:

The library of parts is only that large - it doesn't contain everything you need (because it would have to contain everything, as I need other stuff than you do). So one skill you'll eventually have to learn is how to include a not supplied model into LT-Spice.

For some basic elements you can also set the spice parameters yourself with a CTRL + rightclick on the component and filling out the "spice model" line.

Answer (score 2):

When you're in the drawing editor, left click on the "GET" icon on the menu bar (it looks like an AND gate and it's right between the diode and the open hand) and a dialog will pop up. Find "NPN" and click on it, and then click OK and the part will appear on the drawing. Mouse over to where you want it to be and left click once again to place it.

Now, if you right-click on the NPN, a dialog box will appear. Left click on "Pick New Transistor" and a list of all the NPN transistors in LTspice's library will appear. Find "2N2222" and left-click on it, then left-click on OK, and the NPN on your drawing will have changed into a 2222.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of LTSpice, select the npn2 transistor, not the non choice, and then follow the described instructions.

Comment: '*Follow the described instructions*' -- described where? Please add further details to your answer.